# How to remove white circles around Android icons?

Tags: user-interface, app-icons, graphics

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the white circle that appears around all the freeform app icons? It seems like a terrible design aesthetic in this case where there is no other solid white in the GUI. I am running an Xperia XZ1 with android 9.0 and there is a setting in the launcher for 'add white circular background' that does nothing when turned off. Maybe I need to downgrade my version of android to 8.0 in order for this setting to work?

[image: home screen on xperia]

by contrast, on a moto g 1st gen running lollipop, the homescreen appears beautiful with all the freeform icons intact. Why is Android taking this path of degrading design?

[image: moto g homescreen]

Comment: The "white circle" is just the current Android theme. From time to time Google invents a new "cool" style how icons should look. You can try to change the shape in developer options: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/change-your-home-screen-icon-shapes-android-10-0194758/

Comment: well might as well try downgrading to oreo then ..

Comment: Android has a built in downgrade protection. Only on unlocked/rooted devices you can downgrade and of course only when there is a lower version for that device.